# How to inject each concrete class in a separate service instance?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I want to run multiple `HostedServices` that inject an `IAnimal` each. How can I make sure that 5 distinct instances of a `HostedService` run for each `IAnimal` I have?

At the moment I'm doing the following, but it feels dirty:

**AnimalDependencyResolver.cs**

```
public interface IDependencyResolver<out TResolve>
{
    TResolve GetDependency();
}

public class AnimalDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver<IAnimal>
{
    private int _currentIndex = 0;
    private readonly int _animalCount = 0;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IAnimal> _animals;

    public AnimalDependencyResolver(IEnumerable<IAnimal> animals)
    {
        _animals = animals;
        _animalCount = _animals.Count();
    }

    public IAnimal GetDependency()
    {
        if (_animalCount <= 0 || _currentIndex >= _animalCount)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no (more) elements");

        return _animals.ElementAt(_currentIndex++);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService>();
services.AddScoped<IAnimal, MajesticSeaFlapFlap>();    
services.AddScoped<IAnimal, TrashPanda>();
services.AddScoped<IAnimal, FartSquirrel>();
services.AddScoped<IAnimal, DangerFloof>();
services.AddScoped<IAnimal, NopeRope>();
services.AddSingleton<IDependencyResolver<IAnimal>, AnimalDependencyResolver>();
```

**AnimalService.cs**

```
public AnimalService(ILogger<AnimalService> logger, IDependencyResolver<IAnimal> animalResolver)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _animal = animalResolver.GetDependency();
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: in your constructor what happens if you request an array or a list of the instance? I know with some IoC containers if you ask for an array it will give you all implemented instances. If you want a specific instance then you might need to look at something like named or keyed scopes.

Comment: I have updated the question, you were too quick to comment sorry :)

Comment: Ah, so the answer I posted probably too needs a review. Sorry.

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around this. How do you plan on resolving the `IAnimalService`. Since you have five all registered in identical ways but then you ask for only one from the dependency resolver.

Comment: @Joe_DM No worries! I run 5 `HostedServices` which each need an instance of the `IAnimal`. The dependency resolver resolves an `IAnimal`, not a service.

Comment: I can get them registered all at once as generic types, but I can't find a good way to resolve them all back out again. the default container is very limiting. :(
If it is of help, declaring the service like this `public class AnimalService<TAnimal> : IAnimalService<TAnimal> where TAnimal : IAnimal` and then registering it like this `services.AddScoped(typeof(IAnimalService<>), typeof(AnimalService<>));` does let us resolve them like this `provider.GetService<IAnimalService<IAnimal>>();` but I always get the same one back. I can't pass the right `IEnumerable` type to get a list.

Comment: Hopefully an answer comes along. I'm sure there's gotta be a way without writing a full custom factory service. If you get stuck though, maybe look at using a third party IoC container such as Autofac. It should let you do a lot more, like registering different named instances of each of the services and letting you pick the right one through `Attributes` or a range of options. https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time, I appreciate it! I'll try finding a solution, when I got one I'll post it here.

Comment: this is kind of yuck but you could register each animal as it's concrete type and then resolve off of generics. I don't recommend it but maybe the concept can be expanded to work somehow? e.g. https://i.imgur.com/bi0BD6w.png

Answer (score 0):

I would go the other way. Create a hosted service `AnimalProcessingHost` that resolves all animals and just spawns a task per animal doing the work you need. In starting method do a simple LINQ:

```cs
_tasks = animals
   .Select(a => {
      var service = dependencyResolver.GetRequiredService<IAnimalService>();
      return service.ProcessAsync(a, cancellationTokenFromHostedService); // or even better, wrap in Task.Run
   }).ToList();
```

That way, as soon as you register new animal, you get it processed.  `IAnimalService` is no longer a `IHostedService`, just a service that does the long work, registered as transient.

Alternatively, you can make generic (`AnimalService<T> where T : IAnimal`) and register them like this:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService<Tiger>>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService<Dog>>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService<Cat>>();
```

But then you need to remember to add this line per animal, so maybe write an extension method that scans the assembly for animals and does the registering for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need the IAnimals registered in the container for some other reason than just to inject them to the services... Otherwise it would be enough to make your service generic and construct your animal instances through reflection before being consumed.

In your case you need to create a scope in the hosted services so you can pull out new instances of your animals. If you don't, there is no point in having the animals in the DI container in the first place - they will effectively become singletons once injected.

```cs
interface IAnimalService {}

class AnimalService<T> : IAnimalService, IHostedService where T : IAnimal
{
  private readonly IServiceProvider sp;
  public AnimalService(IServiceProvider sp) => this.sp = sp;

  public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    var needsToProcessANewInstanceOfAnimal = true;
    while (needsToProcessANewInstanceOfAnimal)
    {
      await using var scope = this.sp.CreateAsyncScope();

      // Be aware that this will lead to O(n^2) complexity and unnecessary instantiation
      // I would not recommend this for thousands of specimens
      var animals = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<IAnimal>>();
      T? myAnimal = animals.FirstOrDefault(a => typeof(a).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
                    as T;

      await this.ConsumeAsync(myAnimal, stoppingToken);

      needsToProcessANewInstanceOfAnimal = this.DoWeNeedAnotherAnimal();
    }
  }

  private Task ConsumeAsync(T? animal, CancellationToken ct){...}
}
```

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService<AnimalType1>>();
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService<AnimalType2>>();
services.AddScoped<IAnimal, AnimalType1>();
services.AddScoped<IAnimal, AnimalType2>();
```

You can simplify the registration using reflecion (and similarly for IAnimals):

```cs
var serviceTypes = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => 
  t.IsInterface 
  && typeof(IAnimalService).IsAssignableFrom(t)
  && typeof(IHostedService).IsAssignableFrom(t)
  && t != typeof(IAnimalService)
);

foreach(var t in serviceTypes)
{
  services.Add(typeof(IHostedService), t, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
}
```

For more than a couple of animal specimen you could alter your animal registration and retrieval and do something like this:

```cs
interface IAnimal<T> where T: IAnimal<T> {}

class AnimalType1: IAnimal<AnimalType1> {}

...

services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService<AnimalType1>>();
services.AddScoped<IAnimal<AnimalType1>, AnimalType1>();

...

class AnimalService<T> : IAnimalService, IHostedService where T : IAnimal<T>
{
  ...
  public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    T? animal = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAnimal<T>>() as T;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps a little

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `AnimalService` like this:

```
public AnimalService(ILogger<AnimalService> logger, IAnimal animal)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _animal = animal;
}
```

Then configure services like this:

```
var animalTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => typeof(IAnimal).IsAssignableFrom(p))
    .Where(p => p.IsClass)
    .ToList();

var animalTypeEnumerator = animalTypes.GetEnumerator();
services.AddTransient<IAnimal>(sp =>
{
    if (animalTypeEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        return (IAnimal)sp.GetRequiredService(animalTypeEnumerator.Current);
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"No more IAnimal implementations"); // This line should never be reached
});
foreach (var item in animalTypes)
{
    services.AddTransient(item);
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, AnimalService>();
}
```